# How to order a sum in ascending order of the powers?

Tags: sorting

Consider the sum

```
x^1+x^3+x^2+x^4
```

I want to order this sum in such the I have the powers in ascending order

```
x^1+x^2+x^3+x^4
```

And I want the procedure to be completely general, so that i works on any polynomial of any finite order in x. I have tried Expand (I have another series, not the simple example above) and it doesn't order my series the way I want.

Comment: don't you get that by default: `expr = x^1 + x^3 + x^2 + x^4;
expr`?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to define function

```
inverseorder[expr_] := HoldForm[expr /. Plus -> CirclePlus // Evaluate] /. CirclePlus -> Plus
```